# expand children out of parent with overflow:auto

Tags: css, overflow

I want to make css menu, the parent list should have scrolling if it taller than window's height.

For parent I use `max-height` and `overflow-y:auto`.

What should I do that children don't hide in parent container. They should be shown out of parent.

Here is example
https://codepen.io/matro-skin/pen/jOOgwBB

Comment: Ah, i'm bit confused, you want .child is into scroll bar but .expand is not in scroll bar ?

Comment: @jaydeeppatel I want that `.expand` will not be cut by parent container, smth like this http://prntscr.com/q35yvl

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website OR off-site example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `max-height:100vh;` with `overflow-y:auto;`

Please see below for complete code

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 1rem;
  max-height:100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.child {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.expand {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%; 
  background: #aaa;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;
}
.child:hover .expand {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="expand">Expand</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this code as same as mine, `.explain` divs still are cut by root div